# Atlas search synonyms don't have impact

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I use Atlas Search in free tier, I have a full text index on multiple fields of a product.
Here is my full text index definition :

```
{
  "analyzer": "lucene.french",
  "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "brand": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.french",
        "indexOptions": "positions",
        "norms": "omit",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
        "store": false,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "category": {
        "fields": {
          "name": {
            "analyzer": "lucene.french",
            "indexOptions": "positions",
            "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
            "store": false,
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "type": "document"
      },
      "color": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.french",
        "indexOptions": "positions",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
        "store": false,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "description": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.french",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
        "store": false,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "gender": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.french",
        "indexOptions": "positions",
        "norms": "omit",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
        "store": false,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "name": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.french",
        "norms": "omit",
        "searchAnalyzer": "lucene.french",
        "store": false,
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "synonyms": [
    {
      "analyzer": "lucene.french",
      "name": "gender_synonym",
      "source": {
        "collection": "gender_synonym"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I activate synonyms on gender words to have the translation working in English and French here an example of synonym document :

```
{
  "mappingType": "equivalent",
  "synonyms": [
    "masculin",
    "male",
    "homme",
    "man"
  ]
}
```

When I use the synonym in a pipeline with $search I don't see any impact on the score of the results.
Here is my $search pipeline :

```
[
  {
    $search: {
          index: 'search',
          compound: {
            minimumShouldMatch: 2,
            should: [
              {
                text: {
                  query: "tee shirt rose homme",
                  path: ['category'],
                  score: {
                    boost: {
                      value: 5,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                text: {
                  query: "tee shirt rose homme",
                  path: ['gender'],
                  score: {
                    boost: {
                      value: 5,
                    },
                  },
                  synonyms: "gender_synonym"
                },
              },
              {
                text: {
                  query: "tee shirt rose homme",
                  path: ['color', 'brand', 'name'],
                  score: {
                    boost: {
                      value: 1.5,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                text: {
                  query: "tee shirt rose homme",
                  path: 'description',
                  score: {
                    boost: {
                      value: 1,
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
  }
]
```

As you can see in my query there is the word homme which is in my synonym document.
Did i do something wrong ?